# Fun with sessions

Tags: php, mysql, oop, session, authentication

I've a problem that annoy me very much. It's because I'm trying to make a PHP login script. But when I log in correctly, it'll not let me in.

If I comment out some lines (I'll mark them), the script works, but that's the code I was planning to use to check in on every page, so people don't can come in if they don't should have access.

Below, I've posted the code.

---

### index.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
 require_once "./functions/" . $class_name . ".php";
}
$functions = new functions;
$functions->header("Log ind",0);
$login = new login;
$login->showLogin();
$functions->footer();
?>
```

---

### /functions/functions.php

```
<?php
// Define class functions
class functions {
 function header($titel,$needlogin = 1) {
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['navn'];
// The following lines can be commented out, and it's working
  if($needlogin == 1) {
   if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: http://hansensopskrifter.co.cc/");
    exit;
   }
  }
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
   <head>
    <title><?php echo $titel; ?> - Hansens Opskrifter</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
    <h1>Hansens Opskrifter</h1>
  <?php
// The above lines can be commented out, and it's working
 }

 function footer() {
  ?>
   </body>
  </html>
  <?php
 }
}
?>
```

---

### /functions/mysql.php

```
<?php
// Create the class MySQL
class mysql {
 function __construct() {
  $this->mysqlconnect();
 }

 function mysqlconnect() {
  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
  if(!$conn) {
   die("Noget gik galt - kontakt Kristoffer og vis ham den følgende meddelelse: " . mysql_error());
  }
  if(!mysql_select_db("db",$conn)) {
   die("Noget gik galt - kontakt Kristoffer og vis ham den følgende meddelelse: " . mysql_error());
  }
 }

 function mysqlquery($query) {
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if($result) {
   return $result;
  }
 }
}
?>
```

---

### login.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
 require_once "./functions/" . $class_name . ".php";
}
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$login = new login;
$l = $login->doLogin($name,$pass);
if($l == TRUE) {
 header("Location: http://hansensopskrifter.co.cc/loggedin.php");
} else {
 exit;
}
?>
```

---

### /functions/login.php

```
<?php
class login {
 function __autoload($class_name) {
  require_once($class_name . ".php");
 }
 function showLogin() {
  ?>
  <h2>Log ind</h2>
  <form action="./login.php" method="post">
   Navn:<input type="text" name="name" />
   Kode:<input type="password" name="pass" />
   <input type="submit" value="Log ind" />
  </form>
  <p><a href="./forgotpass.php" alt="Glemt kode" title="Glemt kode">Glemt kode?</a></p>
  <?php
 }

 function doLogin($name,$pass) {
  $mysql = new mysql;
  $n = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
  if(!$n) {
   $functions = new functions;
   $functions->header("Intet navn indtastet",0);
   echo "Du glemte at indtaste dit navn.";
   $this->showLogin();
   $functions->footer();
   return false;
  } elseif(!$pass) {
   $functions = new functions;
   $functions->header("Ingen adgangskode indtastet",0);
   echo "Du glemte at indtaste din adgangskode.";
   $this->showLogin();
   $functions->footer();
  }
  $query = "SELECT `id`, `navn`, `kode` FROM `users` WHERE `navn` = '".$n."' ";
  $result = $mysql->mysqlquery($query);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $k = sha1($pass);
   $navn = $row['navn'];
   $kode = $row['kode'];
   $n = ucfirst(strtolower($n));
   if($navn == $n && $kode == $k) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['navn'] = $row['navn'];
    return true;
   } else {
    $functions = new functions;
    $functions->header("Forkert navn eller kode",0);
    echo "Det indtastede navn eller kode er forkert.";
    $this->showLogin();
    $functions->footer();
    return false;
   }
  }
 }
}
?>
```

---

### loggedin.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
 require_once ("./functions/" . $class_name . ".php");
}
header( "refresh:2;url=./panel/index.php",0);
$functions = new functions;
$functions->header("Logger ind...");
?>
<p>Du er nu logget ind. Du vil automatisk blive viderestillet om omkring 5 sekunder. Hvis du er tr&aelig;t af at vente kan du <a href="./panel/index.php" alt="Opskrifter" title="Opskrifter">klikke her</a>.</p>
<?php
$functions->footer();
?>
```

---

I've tried a lot of things, and now, I just hope you can help me. I've checked that there is a cookie that's created called PHPSESSID on my computer.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I don't have too much time to see your code and classes, but it seems that at loggedin.php `$functions->header("Logger ind...");` you are missing a parameter to tell the function this visitor does not need to log in: `$functions->header("Logger ind...",0);`. At a first glance, your method does not seem to be simple or effective

Comment: I couldn't find the login related problem but a part of your problem is definatly that your code is a horrible, tangled mess of mixed HTML and PHP and horribly named classes, variables and functions... and what the hell are you trying with the `header( "refresh:2;url=./panel/index.php",0);`? Anyways, did you check if the session variable actually gets set?

Comment: It is probably not very secure either. I can log in as any user id by faking my cookie.

Comment: In [Autoloading Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) it's not reported that a class can implement the method `__autoload()`, and it will be automatically called to load class files. You need to register the method using [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php); in that case, the method should be static. It's then enough to define `__autoload()` in a file that is include all times; there is no need to declare it in each file.

Comment: How would you make it more simple and effective, Ast?
And it's only the PHPSESSID that's in the cookie, but if it can give a risk, how would you make it?

Comment: kiamlaluno: Can you please give me some kind of code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only isset is not enough. Even if a variable is 0 then also isset returns true.

Try using the following code:

> if
>   ((isset($_SESSION['id']))&&($_SESSION['id']!=0)) {
>
> ```
> $login = new login;
>
> $login->showLogin();
>
> exit(); }
> ```

Comment: In /functions/functions.php line number 7

Comment: Thank you very much - it's all fixed now. I've accepted your answer - it's amazing, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's a huge wall of text, but it would appear the flaw's in your index.php:

```
$login = new login;
$login->showLogin();
```

You unconditionally create a login object and display the login form, without ever checking if a previous login attempt succeeded. I don't know if the `$_SESSION['id']` and `$_SESSION['navn']` you set in the login class are to indicate a successful login or not, but assuming they are, you should have something like:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // not logged in, show the form
    $login = new login;
    $login->showLogin();
    exit();
}
// show logged in content here
```

Comment: And that's why I've this code in the header:
`if($needlogin == 1) {
   if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: http://hansensopskrifter.co.cc/");
    exit;
   }`

This should check if the user is logged in correctly, and is included on every page. If the variable is set to 0, it'll not be checked.

Comment: But if http://hansensopskrifter.co.cc's default document is that index.php you've got above, then you're right back at the login form.

Comment: It is the default document, but if the login is correct, it should redirect to /panel/index.php

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see after a quick look is that you do this:

```
echo $_SESSION['navn'];
```

before you run

```
header("Location: http://hansensopskrifter.co.cc/");
```

That will not work. You can't output anything before you write an HTTP header. Remove that echo, or put it after the `header()`.

Comment: I know that, and it was for testing purposes I set that in. It doesn't give me the error.